# Synchronization mode in mutex protected block

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, memory-fences

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/atomic/usage_examples.html

In the "Singleton with double-checked locking pattern" example of the above boost examples, are the memory_order_consume for the second load of _instance and the memory_order_release for the store of _instance necessary?  I thought the scoped_lock has acquire and release semantics already and the first load of _instance has synchronization mode memory_order_consume.

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that the `boost` primitives used here support the same functionality as their `std` counterparts, the second `load` does not require `memory_order_consume` since it is guaranteed
to be synchronized with the `store/release` based on the acquire/release semantics of the `mutex`, you are right about that.

Perhaps, the use of `memory_order_consume` was based on the false assumption that a `load/relaxed` may float up across the `mutex/acquire` barrier,
but this is not possible per the `mutex` guarantees and as such `memory_order_relaxed` is perfectly fine.

The `store/release` on the other hand is absolutely necessary because it synchronizes with the first `load/consume` which is not protected by the `mutex`.